# Propagating touch event through view hierarchy (UIButton inside UIView)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uitapgesturerecognizer

Pretty sure this is an easy one, still couldn’t find anything similar on the Internet–one more reason to believe it is a non-issue. Anyways!

*How can I [put a `UIButton` inside a `UIView`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJb0I.png) and add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the view calling a function in this view while still executing the button action at the same time?*

**What I have:**

- Tapping inside the button executes the button action only.
- Tapping outside the button executes the view function only.

**What I want:**

- Tapping inside the button executes both, button action and view function.
- Tapping outside the button executes the view function only.

UPDATE (the code I used):

```swift
import UIKit
import AwesomeFramework

class View: UIView {

    let button = UIButton()
    let awesomeObject = AwesomeFramework.AwesomeObject()

    @objc func a(_ sender: Any) {
        // never gets called
        print("a")
    }

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor),
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor),
            ])

        button.addTarget(awesomeObject, action: #selector(awesomeAction), for: .touchUpInside) // awesomeAction prints "b"

        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(a(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Tapping on the button I want:

```
b
a
```

or

```
a
b
```

I get:

```
b
```

UPDATE: adjusted the example with some restrictions, like:

- The button triggers an action in a framework I don’t have access to
- There actually are many buttons and other tap-receiving elements. I do not want to a the a-function to all of them (also I can’t as some of the elements manage their own recognizers)

Answer (score 0):

inside you selector for UITapGestureRecognizer, you can check which view is the gesture triggered from. and since you can access the view, you can check the tag of sending view and identify if it was triggered by your button.

this is how you can do it:

```
@objc func a(_ sender: Any) {
    if let gesture = sender as? UITapGestureRecognizer, let v = gesture.view, v.tag == self.button.tag {
        return //since it has the tag same as that you had set for button, return
    }
    // else do what you wanted to.
}
```

you can have your selector linked as:

```
#selector(a(_:))
```

and defined as:

```
func a(_ sender: Any) { .....}
```

be sure to tag your button by doing:

```
self.button.tag = 9 //(or any number you prefer)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this might help me, even with the added info in the question.

Comment: Sadly `@objc func a(_ sender: Any)` is not being triggered (as b() is, and touches are not propagated to a()). So I can not perform that check.

Comment: @TrevorFreeman did you change this:  `UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(a))` to this: `UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(a(_:)))`

Comment: Yes, I did (and SO wants this comment to be at least 15 characters in length, so I state that fact as well)

Comment: @TrevorFreeman can you post the code where you are instantiating this view and adding it as a subview to the superview ?

Comment: I used the exact same way like I did instantiate and add the button in the above example

Comment: @TrevorFreeman I need to see where you are holding the reference to the View. Can you at-least paste the method where you are adding the subview? that might help !!

Answer (score 0):

A button can have multiple targets. Tell the button to trigger both `a` and `b`:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(a), for: .touchUpInside)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(b), for: .touchUpInside)
```

What if the user puts his finger down in the button, then drags out of the button before releasing? If you want that to also trigger the `a` action, do this too:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(a), for: .touchUpOutside)
```

Comment: Thank you! Good hint with the .touchUpOutside! I think I will have to find another way though because I actually do have many buttons and other touchy elements (updated the question accordingly).